# A Better Tournament Structure to Identify Top Ranks

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The Olympic events often use a simple tournament structure, sometimes with repechage,
starting from 16 teams.  But, even in an ideal world where "teams are ordered and the better
team always wins", this does not guarantee that the third-best team gets a medal
(because it can be eliminated by the best and second-best teams in its early matches).

So, what is the minimum number of rounds needed to properly give the gold, silver, and
bronze medals to 16 starting teams?

Also, up to how many teams (above 16), does this minimum number of rounds stay the same?

I require that the two teams in every match must have played the same number of prior
matches.

Comment: One way would be to run a tournament to find the best player, then take the players who were beat by the player who won, and run a tournament with them (and an extra player, to even out the number of matches). This gives second place. Then, take everyone beat by second place and run a tournament with them (and an extra player). At worst, this requires $22$ games, and no team plays more than $6$ games. (Although I might have messed up the numbers)

Comment: Also, how do you define the number of "rounds" in a tournament? Is it the number of matches between two teams? Or the maximum number of matches played by any single team? Or the number of concurrently occurring sets of matches?

Comment: Rounds is "the number of concurrently occurring sets of matches".  (But, I'm somewhat open to changing this definition to "the maximum number of matches played by any single team" if its solution is more elegant.)

Comment: Men's football at the 2008 Olympics is a great example of the problem with current tournaments: Nigeria took the silver and Brazil took the bronze.  But, all results would also be consistent with Brazil being the silver team.  Or (assuming Nigeria was truly better than Brazil, which is also consistent), all results would also be consistent with Ivory Coast, or Netherlands, being the bronze team.  So, fair logic should have given silver medals to both Nigeria and Brazil, and bronze medals to both Ivory Coast and Netherlands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with a 4-round tournament (always pairing teams with identical W/L sequences) to yield 8 qualifiers (from 16 starting teams):

```
WWWW
WWWL
WWLW
WLWW
LWWW
WWLL
WLWL
WLLW
```

5th round:

```
WWWL vs LWWW (5A)
WWLW vs WLWW (5B)
WWLL vs WLWL (5C)
WWWW vs WLLW (5D: WWWW should win)
```

6th round:

```
5Aloser  vs 5Bloser  (6A)
5Awinner vs 5Bwinner (6B)
5Cwinner vs 5Dwinner (6C: WWWW should win)
```

7th round:

```
6Awinner vs 6Bloser (7A)
6Cwinner vs 6Bwinner (7B: WWWW should win)
```

Then, 7Bwinner gets the gold, 7Bloser gets silver, and 7Awinner gets bronze.

This is the best I could do, and I intentionally kept the drama of the final match
being for gold.  I don't see a way to get more than 16 starting teams filtered to
the top 3 in only 7 rounds, but believe it's possible, so I still hope someone makes
a better answer!